# Failed to install i2c in node-red

Tags: installation, node-red, i2c

I am new with node-red
I want to install i2c bus in node-red. But it is showing error

I have tried to install from this link:https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-i2c

I have also updated npm and node.js versions

This is my console output

```
C:\Users\dcube>npm install node-red-contrib-i2c

> i2c-bus@3.2.0 install C:\Users\dcube\node_modules\i2c-bus
> node-gyp rebuild

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! i2c-bus@1.2.5 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the i2c-bus@1.2.5 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\dcube\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-08-26T08_05_40_019Z-debug.log

C:\Users\dcube>npm install -g n stable
npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM
npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for n@6.0.1: wanted {"os":"!win32","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    !win32
npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  any
npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   win32
npm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: x64

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\dcube\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-08-26T08_13_56_860Z-debug.log
```

Please help me out to get rid of this error

Answer (score 0):

Neither of the nodes you are trying to install support the Windows operating system so will not install.

If you want to use the i2c Node-RED nodes then you will need to run on Linux.